# django: prefetch related objects of a GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, optimization, foreign-keys, generic-foreign-key

Suppose I have a model `Box` with a `GenericForeignKey` that points to either an `Apple` instance or a `Chocolate` instance. `Apple` and `Chocolate`, in turn, have ForeignKeys to `Farm` and `Factory`, respectively. I want to display a list of `Box`es, for which I need to access `Farm` and `Factory`. How do I do this in as few DB queries as possible?

Minimal illustrative example:

```
class Farm(Model):
    ...

class Apple(Model):
    farm = ForeignKey(Farm)
    ...

class Factory(Model):
    ...

class Chocolate(Model):
    factory = ForeignKey(Factory)
    ...

class Box(Model)
    content_type = ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.content_type == ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Apple):
            apple = self.content_object
            return "Apple {} from Farm {}".format(apple, apple.farm)
        elif self.content_type == ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Chocolate):
            chocolate = self.content_object
            return "Chocolate {} from Factory {}".format(chocolate, chocolate.factory)
```

Here are a few things I tried. In all these examples, **N** is the number of Boxes. The query count assumes that the `ContentType`s for `Apple` and `Chocolate` have already been cached, so the `get_for_model()` calls do not hit the DB.

1) Naive:

`print [box for box in Box.objects.all()]`

This does **1** (fetch Boxes) + **N** (fetch Apple or Chocolate for each Box) + **N** (fetch Farm for each Apple and Factory for each Chocolate) queries.

2) `select_related` doesn't help here, because `Box.content_object` is a `GenericForeignKey`.

3) As of django 1.4, `prefetch_related` can fetch `GenericForeignKey`s.

`print [box for box in Box.objects.prefetch_related('content_object').all()]`

This does **1** (fetch Boxes) + **2** (fetch Apples and Chocolates for all Boxes) + **N** (fetch Farm for each Apple and Factory for each Chocolate) queries.

4) Apparently `prefetch_related` isn't smart enough to follow ForeignKeys of GenericForeignKeys. If I try:

`print [box for box in Box.objects.prefetch_related(
    'content_object__farm',
    'content_object__factory').all()]`

it rightfully complains that `Chocolate` objects don't have a `farm` field, and vice versa.

5) I could do:

```
apple_ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Apple)
chocolate_ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Chocolate)
boxes_with_apples = Box.objects.filter(content_type=apple_ctype).prefetch_related('content_object__farm')
boxes_with_chocolates = Box.objects.filter(content_type=chocolate_ctype).prefetch_related('content_object__factory')
```

This does **1** (fetch Boxes) + **2** (fetch Apples and Chocolates for all Boxes) + **2** (fetch Farms for all Apples and Factories for all Chocolates) queries. The downside is that I have to merge and sort the two querysets (`boxes_with_apples`, `boxes_with_chocolates`) manually. In my real application, I'm displaying these Boxes in a paginated ModelAdmin. It's not obvious how to integrate this solution there. Maybe I could write a custom Paginator to do this caching transparently?

6) I could cobble together something based on [this](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/02/22/django-patterns-part-4-forwards-generic-relations/) that also does O(1) queries. But I'd rather not mess with internals (`_content_object_cache`) if I can avoid it.

In summary: **Printing a Box requires access to the ForeignKeys of a GenericForeignKey. How can I print N Boxes in O(1) queries?** Is (5) the best I can do, or is there a simpler solution?

Bonus points: **How would you refactor this DB schema to make such queries easier?**

Comment: If you rename `farm`/`factory` to some common name, like `creator`, will prefetch_related work?

Comment: Indeed, `prefetch_related('content_object__creator')` works after your suggested rename. Unfortunately the rename might or might not make sense depending on the actual models that you have in place of Apple/Farm and Chocolate/Factory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can manually implement something like `prefetch_selected` and use Django's `select_related` method, that will make join in database query.

```
apple_ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Apple)
chocolate_ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Chocolate)
boxes = Box.objects.all()
content_objects = {}
# apples
content_objects[apple_ctype.id] = Apple.objects.select_related(
    'farm').in_bulk(
        [b.object_id for b in boxes if b.content_type == apple_ctype]
    )
# chocolates
content_objects[chocolate_ctype.id] = Chocolate.objects.select_related(
    'factory').in_bulk(
        [b.object_id for b in boxes if b.content_type == chocolate_ctype]
    )
```

This should make only 3 queries (`get_for_model` queries are omitted). The [`in_bulk`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.in_bulk) method returns a dict in the format {id: model}. So to get your content_object you need a code like:

```
content_obj = content_objects[box.content_type_id][box.object_id]
```

However I'm not sure if this code will be quicker than your **O(5)** solution as it requires additional iteration over boxes queryset and it also generates a query with a `WHERE id IN (...)` statement.

But if you sort boxes only by fields from Box model you can fill the `content_objects` dict after pagination. But you need to pass `content_objects` to `__unicode__` somehow.

> How would you refactor this DB schema to make such queries easier?

We have a similar structure. We store `content_object` in `Box`, but instead of `object_id` and `content_object` we use `ForeignKey(Box)` in `Apple` and `Chocolate`. In `Box` we have a `get_object` method to return the Apple or Chocolate model. In this case we can use `select_related`, but in most of our use-cases we filter Boxes by content_type. So we have the same problems like your 5th option. But we started our project on Django 1.2 when there was no prefetch_selected.

If you rename farm/factory to some common name, like creator, will prefetch_related work?

About your **option 6**

I can't say anything against filling `_content_object_cache`. 
If you don't like to deal with internals you can fill a custom property and then use

```
apple = getattr(self, 'my_custop_prop', None)
if apple is None:
    apple = self.content_object
```

Comment: Just noticed that my answer is very close to your *option 6* but with less automatisation. I've never read that article before. Also that doesn't look like O(1), it's rather O(2 + number_of_unique_ctypes)