# Is django prefetch_related supposed to work with GenericRelation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

**UPDATE 2022:** The original ticked [#24272](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24272) which I opened 8 years ago about this issue is now closed in favor of [#33651](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33651), which once implemented will give us a new syntax to do this type of prefetches.

**============== END OF UPDATE ==============**

What's all about?

Django has a [GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation) class, which adds a **“reverse” generic relationship** to enable an additional **API**.

It turns out we can use this `reverse-generic-relation` for `filtering` or `ordering`, but we can't use it inside `prefetch_related`.

I was wondering if this is a bug, or its not supposed to work, or its something that can be implemented in the feature.

Let me show you with some examples what I mean.

Lets say we have two main models: `Movies` and `Books`.

- `Movies` have a `Director`
- `Books` have an `Author`

And we want to assign tags to our `Movies` and `Books`, but instead of using `MovieTag` and `BookTag` models, we want to use a single `TaggedItem` class with a `GFK` to `Movie` or `Book`.

Here is the model structure:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag


class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director)
    tags = GenericRelation(TaggedItem, related_query_name='movies')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    tags = GenericRelation(TaggedItem, related_query_name='books')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And some initial data:

```
>>> from tags.models import Book, Movie, Author, Director, TaggedItem
>>> a = Author.objects.create(name='E L James')
>>> b1 = Book.objects.create(name='Fifty Shades of Grey', author=a)
>>> b2 = Book.objects.create(name='Fifty Shades Darker', author=a)
>>> b3 = Book.objects.create(name='Fifty Shades Freed', author=a)
>>> d = Director.objects.create(name='James Gunn')
>>> m1 = Movie.objects.create(name='Guardians of the Galaxy', director=d)
>>> t1 = TaggedItem.objects.create(content_object=b1, tag='roman')
>>> t2 = TaggedItem.objects.create(content_object=b2, tag='roman')
>>> t3 = TaggedItem.objects.create(content_object=b3, tag='roman')
>>> t4 = TaggedItem.objects.create(content_object=m1, tag='action movie')
```

So as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) show we can do stuff like this.

```
>>> b1.tags.all()
[<TaggedItem: roman>]
>>> m1.tags.all()
[<TaggedItem: action movie>]
>>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(books__author__name='E L James')
[<TaggedItem: roman>, <TaggedItem: roman>, <TaggedItem: roman>]
>>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(movies__director__name='James Gunn')
[<TaggedItem: action movie>]
>>> Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('tags')
[<Book: Fifty Shades of Grey>, <Book: Fifty Shades Darker>, <Book: Fifty Shades Freed>]
>>> Book.objects.filter(tags__tag='roman')
[<Book: Fifty Shades of Grey>, <Book: Fifty Shades Darker>, <Book: Fifty Shades Freed>]
```

But, if we try to `prefetch` some `related data` of `TaggedItem` via this `reverse generic relation`, we are going to get an **AttributeError**.

```
>>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related('books')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'object_id'
```

Some of you may ask, why I just don't use `content_object` instead of `books` here? The reason is, because this only work when we want to:

1. `prefetch` only one level deep from `querysets` containing different type of `content_object`.

   ```
   >>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related('content_object')
   [<TaggedItem: roman>, <TaggedItem: roman>, <TaggedItem: roman>, <TaggedItem: action movie>]
   ```
2. `prefetch` many levels but from `querysets` containing only one type of `content_object`.

   ```
   >>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(books__author__name='E L James').prefetch_related('content_object__author')
   [<TaggedItem: roman>, <TaggedItem: roman>, <TaggedItem: roman>]
   ```

But, if we want both 1) and 2) (to `prefetch` many levels from `queryset` containing different types of `content_objects`, we can't use `content_object`.

```
>>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related('content_object__author')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'author_id'
```

`Django` thinks that all `content_objects` are `Books`, and thus they have an `Author`.

Now imagine the situation where we want to `prefetch` not only the `books` with their `author`, but also the `movies` with their `director`. Here are few attempts.

The silly way:

```
>>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related(
...     'content_object__author',
...     'content_object__director',
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'author_id'
```

Maybe with custom `Prefetch` object?

```
>>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related(
...     Prefetch('content_object', queryset=Book.objects.all().select_related('author')),
...     Prefetch('content_object', queryset=Movie.objects.all().select_related('director')),
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: Custom queryset can't be used for this lookup.
```

Some solutions of this problem are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466945/django-prefetch-related-objects-of-a-genericforeignkey). But that's a lot of massage over the data which I want to avoid.
I really like the API coming from the `reversed generic relations`, it would be very nice to be able to do `prefetchs` like that:

```
>>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related(
...     'books__author',
...     'movies__director',
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'object_id'
```

Or like that:

```
>>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related(
...     Prefetch('books', queryset=Book.objects.all().select_related('author')),
...     Prefetch('movies', queryset=Movie.objects.all().select_related('director')),
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'object_id'
```

But as you can see, we aways get that **AttributeError**.
I'm using Django `1.7.3` and Python `2.7.6`. And i'm curious why Django is throwing that error? Why is Django searching for an `object_id` in the `Book` model?
**Why I think this may be a bug?**
Usually when we ask `prefetch_related` to resolve something it can't, we see:

```
>>> TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related('some_field')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: Cannot find 'some_field' on TaggedItem object, 'some_field' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

But here, it is different. Django actually tries to resolve the relation... and fails. Is this a bug which should be reported? I have never reported anything to Django so that's why I'm asking here first. I'm unable to trace the error and decide for myself if this is a bug, or a feature which could be implemented.

Comment: Ok looking at the Django Source I would say that this not a bug, but simply not supported... If you want to get the authors with the books you would need to use `select_related()` as this is a `ForeignKey` relation. To use this together with `prefetch_related` you would need to use a custom queryset which is currently [not supported](https://github.com/django/django/blob/84b6c768301096849f5589d7612b129c5445abd3/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py#L170) by Django for generic relations.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I [opened a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24272) about this. Hope one day this feature will make it thru to the ORM : )

Comment: The PR was [merged](https://github.com/django/django/pull/17136) in django:main 3 weeks ago!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`prefetch_related_objects` to the rescue.

Starting from Django 1.10 *(Note: it still presents in the previous versions, but was not part of the public API.)*, we can use [prefetch_related_objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related-objects) to divide and conquer our problem.

`prefetch_related` is an operation, where Django fetches related data **after** the queryset has been evaluated (doing a second query after the main one has been evaluated). And in order to work, it expects the items in the queryset to be homogeneous (the same type). The main reason the reverse generic generation does not work right now is that we have objects from different content types, and the code is not yet smart enough to separate the flow for different content types.

Now using `prefetch_related_objects` we do fetches only on a **subset** of our queryset where all the items will be homogeneous. Here is an example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import prefetch_related_objects
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from tags.models import TaggedItem, Book, Movie


tagged_items = TaggedItem.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(tagged_items, 25)
page = paginator.get_page(1)

# prefetch books with their author
# do this only for items where
# tagged_item.content_object is a Book
book_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Book)
tags_with_books = [item for item in page.object_list if item.content_type_id == book_ct.id]
prefetch_related_objects(tags_with_books, "content_object__author")

# prefetch movies with their director
# do this only for items where
# tagged_item.content_object is a Movie
movie_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Movie)
tags_with_movies = [item for item in page.object_list if item.content_type_id == movie_ct.id]
prefetch_related_objects(tags_with_movies, "content_object__director")

# This will make 5 queries in total
# 1 for page items
# 1 for books
# 1 for book authors
# 1 for movies
# 1 for movie directors
# Iterating over items wont make other queries
for item in page.object_list:
    # do something with item.content_object
    # and item.content_object.author/director
    print(
        item,
        item.content_object,
        getattr(item.content_object, 'author', None),
        getattr(item.content_object, 'director', None)
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? Because it fires same `ValueError: Custom queryset can't be used for this lookup.`. And also you have syntax errors with missing parenthesis.

Comment: To be honest I don't remember, however, did some testing now and updated the answer with a working example. Unfortunately custom querysets in the `Prefetch` object seems like cannot work with `GenericForeignKey`, thus we cannot do `select_related` on the Book/Movie querysets, to fetch author/director.

Comment: Note: You can use `ContentType.objects.get_for_models(Book, Movie)` to further reduce the queries.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to retrieve `Book` instances and prefetch the related tags use `Book.objects.prefetch_related('tags')`. No need to use the reverse relation here.

You can also have a look at the related tests in the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/prefetch_related/tests.py#L738).

Also the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) states that `prefetch_related()` is supposed to work with `GenericForeignKey` and `GenericRelation`:

> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related. It also supports prefetching of `GenericRelation` and `GenericForeignKey`.

**UPDATE:** To prefetch the `content_object` for a `TaggedItem` you can use `TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related('content_object')`, if you want to limit the result to only tagged `Book` objects you could additionally filter for the `ContentType` (not sure if `prefetch_related` works with the `related_query_name`). If you also want to get the `Author` together with the book you need to use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) not `prefetch_related()` as this is a `ForeignKey` relationship, you can combine this in a [custom `prefetch_related()` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models import Prefetch

book_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Book)
TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type=book_ct).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'content_object',  
        queryset=Book.objects.all().select_related('author')
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Bernhard. The problem is that what i really need is to `prefetch` `books` with their `author` from a `TaggetItem` `queryset` **containing** not only `books`. This mean i need something like this: TaggedItem.objects.all().prefetch_related('books__author'). But that throws a strange error: **AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'object_id'**. May i ask for your opinion about it? Does it looks to you like a bug which should be reported?

Comment: Some workarounds of this problem are presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466945/django-prefetch-related-objects-of-a-genericforeignkey). But that's a lot of custom massage of the data which i want to avoid. I like the API coming from the `reversed generic relations`, and i believe this is the way of achieving such functionality.

Comment: @Todor I've updated my answer, can't try it out right now but I hope it points you in the right direction... You may want to try it out with the `related_query_name` as well as with filtering for the content_type...

Comment: Thank you again. Actually that's my struggle - is `related_query_name` supposed to work with `prefetch_related`. I've tested it with filtering on `content_type`, but the problem is that the ORM search for an `object_id` attribute inside `Book` model instead of inside `TaggetItem` model. I guess i'm goingo to open a ticket soon.

Comment: The query is: TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type=book_ct).prefetch_related('books'). I know i can use your example, or just use .prefetch_related('content_object__author'). But in my real use case this can't be done because i cant filter on `content_type`. I have to work with `TaggedItems` with `content_types` of type `Book` or `Movie` or something else.

Comment: I will edit my question again to show you why i cant do prefetch's with `content_type` because i feel its not much clear right now.

Comment: Is Bernhard's last updated code supposed to work or is it an attempt to solve a problem? I tried it on generic foreign key, and it throws an error. looking at source code of django (contrib.contenttypes.fields.get_prefetch_queryset), you are not allowed to supply queryset for genericforeign key prefetch.

Comment: @eugene exactly: `Custom queryset can't be used for this lookup.`

Comment: did anyone get the solution of this?

Answer (score 4):

Building on Bernhard's answer, which has a code-snippet at the end that throws the below error in reality:

```
ValueError: Custom queryset can't be used for this lookup.
```

I've overridden the GenericForeignKey to actually allow the behavior, how bulletproof this implementation is, is unknown to me at this time but it seems to get what I need done, so I'm posting it here, hopefully it'll help out others. Please lookout for `START CHANGES` and `END CHANGES` tags to see my changes to the original django code.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey as BaseGenericForeignKey

class CustomGenericForeignKey(BaseGenericForeignKey):
    def get_prefetch_queryset(self, instances, queryset=None):
        """
        Enable passing queryset to get_prefetch_queryset when using GenericForeignKeys but only works when a single
        content type is being queried
        """
        # START CHANGES
        # if queryset is not None:
        #     raise ValueError("Custom queryset can't be used for this lookup.")
        # END CHANGES

        # For efficiency, group the instances by content type and then do one
        # query per model
        fk_dict = defaultdict(set)
        # We need one instance for each group in order to get the right db:
        instance_dict = {}
        ct_attname = self.model._meta.get_field(self.ct_field).get_attname()
        for instance in instances:
            # We avoid looking for values if either ct_id or fkey value is None
            ct_id = getattr(instance, ct_attname)
            if ct_id is not None:
                fk_val = getattr(instance, self.fk_field)
                if fk_val is not None:
                    fk_dict[ct_id].add(fk_val)
                    instance_dict[ct_id] = instance

        ret_val = []
        for ct_id, fkeys in fk_dict.items():
            instance = instance_dict[ct_id]
            # START CHANGES
            if queryset is not None:
                assert len(fk_dict) == 1  # only a single content type is allowed, else undefined behavior
                ret_val.extend(queryset.filter(pk__in=fkeys))
            else:
                ct = self.get_content_type(id=ct_id, using=instance._state.db)
                ret_val.extend(ct.get_all_objects_for_this_type(pk__in=fkeys))
            # END CHANGES

        # For doing the join in Python, we have to match both the FK val and the
        # content type, so we use a callable that returns a (fk, class) pair.
        def gfk_key(obj):
            ct_id = getattr(obj, ct_attname)
            if ct_id is None:
                return None
            else:
                model = self.get_content_type(id=ct_id,
                                              using=obj._state.db).model_class()
                return (model._meta.pk.get_prep_value(getattr(obj, self.fk_field)),
                        model)

        return (
            ret_val,
            lambda obj: (obj.pk, obj.__class__),
            gfk_key,
            True,
            self.name,
            True,
        )
```